# Firefox freezes frequently in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: firefox, freeze, facebook

Firefox freezes frequently in Ubuntu 16.04. It only happens with Firefox, everything else works fine. Most of this occurs when i am browsing facebook, it freezes for a while and then displays `unresponsive script` error. What is the underlying issue?

Comment: There are way too many possible causes for this. Have you tried starting Firefox in Safe Mode and see if you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Ah! Didn't encounter the problem while in safe mode. Any workaround to make the normal mode work fine?

Comment: Most likely the problem is caused by extensions or hardware settings in Firefox. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-extensions-themes-to-fix-problems for a long list of things you can try.

Comment: This happens a lot on my firefox. I bet this has something to do with the current kernel instability that is causing random freezes in the 16.04 and many graphics related issues!

Comment: @skrtbhtngr: But the kernel or hardware drivers cannot cause long running scripts inside Firefox like in OP's case. That must be caused by something executed within Firefox and Firefox doesn't execute kernel code.